# Show MsgBox as DataGRidView cell Value changes

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to Display Message Box as DataGridView cell value Changes

**For Example :-**

Currently DatagridView1 Cell is focused

I will type HELLO

So as i type H it should display msgbox "H"

then when i write E it should display msgbox "HE"

As cell value changes at that time only it should show MSGBOX

Please Help.

Thanks in Advance...!!

Comment: Please read [Ask] ASAP

Comment: Plutonix help if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the KeyPress event.

```
    private void gridView_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if(gridView.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            var cell = gridView.SelectedCells[0];
            if (cell.Value != null)
                MessageBox.Show(cell.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: @ J.Allen Not working brother MsgBox is showing when grid is focused and key is pressed i want to show msg box when cell is in editmode and key is pressed then it should tell which key is pressed..

Comment: You're right.  Apparently the TextBox is the one getting the Key events.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/575dfd63-846e-4bad-93ed-2c3e1eeadc1b/datagridview-keydown-in-editmode?forum=winformsdatacontrols That article shows how you can attach a handler to those events and accomplish what you want.